# WS-Security Framework 1.1 .Net

Tags: .net, web-services, frameworks, ws-security, wse

I'm trying to consume a web service with WS-Security done in Java, from my ASP.NET 1.1 Application. When I call the method of the service, the app shows an error about the proxy, then I create a proxy object and asign the credentials to it, but when I try the request, I get an error like:

> Unable to connect

Should I use WSE?

Please some one help me.
Thanks for your time.

ps. sorry about my english, it's not my language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS-Security is large specification with a lot of related specifications. You must know what exactly do you need. .NET 1.1 has no support for WS-Security. Some support can be added by WSE but there is very big chance that it will simply not cover features you need.

In the worst case you will have to implement part of that specifications by yourselves through custom [SOAP Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapheader.aspx) and [SOAP Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) or you will have to upgrade to newer .NET version supporting WCF and hope that WCF feature set contains features you need.

Comment: thanks. the WS is WS-Security UsernameToken standard, i already try with wcf but it does not work. i can't upgrade framework, cause is a very big application

Comment: UserNameToken is just simple SOAP header (with some additional complexity in case of digested password). You can implement it following the correct version of the standard used by the service.